# show that $d(a,b)\leq r-s-t \Rightarrow K(c,t) \subseteq K(a,r)$ in a metric space, assuming that $r,s,t>0$ and $c \in K(b,s)$.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Alright, so in a metric space, $M$, with $r,s,t>0$, $a,b,c \in M$ and $c \in K(b,s)$ I have to show, that:

$d(a,b)\leq r-s-t \Rightarrow K(c,t) \subseteq K(a,r)$

I really have no idea where to start this. I know the proof for

$d(a,b) \leq r-s \Rightarrow k(b,s) \subseteq K(a,r)$

but I'm not sure how I can expand that to the above (or if that is even how I am supposed to go by it). Can anyone help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is $K(a,r)$ ??

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't think when I posted this. Of course $K(a,r)$ makes no sense - Where I live, english is not the first language, so I was going by our terminology. I think the english terminology is an "open ball", so it should probably be $B(a,r)$ - that is, the open ball with center $a$ and radius $r$.

But I've managed to solve it anyway, so no worries. I will edit my post and include the answer to it once I have the time :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to show is that if you pick an $x$ that lies in the open ball around $c$, then it must also lie in the open ball around $a$. You know an upper bound to both d$(a,b)$, d$(x,c)$ and d$(c,b)$ (make sure you know why and how).

So, write out d$(x,a)$, make use of the triangle inequality a couple of times, and conclude that the following holds: d$(x,a) < r$.